# Missing option to connect to Bitbucket

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

On my first run of Google Cloud Datalab I was able to connect my Bitbucket git repository. Then I deleted my project and VM, and started a new project. But now the option to connect to Bitbucket is missing at Source >Browse.

Anybody suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

turns out you can only connect a repository this way, when you create a project, before you start an actual datalab.